# Can I upload image without filemanager

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

i want to make upload image without file manager , i want upload directory from pc

HTML code

```html
  <div id="tab-image">
          <table id="images" class="list">
          <thead>
           
            <tr>
              <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_title; ?></td>
              <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_link; ?></td>
              <td class="left"><?php echo $entry_image_banner; ?></td>
             <td></td>
            </tr>
            
          </thead>
          <?php $image_row = 0; ?>
          <?php foreach ($shop_images as $shop_image) { ?>
          <tbody id="image-row<?php echo $image_row; ?>">
            <tr>
              <td class="left"><?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
                <input type="text" name="shop_image[<?php echo $image_row; ?>][shop_image_description][<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][title]" value="<?php echo isset($shop_image['shop_image_description'][$language['language_id']]) ? $shop_image['shop_image_description'][$language['language_id']]['title'] : ''; ?>" />
                <img src="catalog/view/theme/mall/image/flags/<?php echo $language['image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /><br />
                <?php if (isset($error_shop_image[$image_row][$language['language_id']])) { ?>
                <span class="error"><?php echo $error_shop_image[$image_row][$language['language_id']]; ?></span>
                <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?></td>
              <td class="left"><input type="text" name="shop_image[<?php echo $image_row; ?>][link]" value="<?php echo $shop_image['link']; ?>" /></td>
              <td class="left"><div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $shop_image['thumb']; ?>" alt="" id="thumb<?php echo $image_row; ?>" />
                  <input type="hidden" name="shop_image[<?php echo $image_row; ?>][image]" value="<?php echo $shop_image['image']; ?>" id="image<?php echo $image_row; ?>"  />
                  <br />
                  <a onclick="image_upload(\'image' + image_row + '\', \'thumb' + image_row + '\');" id="simple-image"><?php echo $text_browse; ?></a>  |  <a onclick="$('#thumb<?php echo $image_row; ?>').attr('src', '<?php echo $no_image; ?>'); $('#image<?php echo $image_row; ?>').attr('value', '');"><?php echo $text_clear; ?></a></div></td>
              <td class="left"><a onclick="$('#image-row<?php echo $image_row; ?>').remove();" class="button"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
          <?php $image_row++; ?>
          <?php } ?>
          <tfoot>
            <tr>
              <td colspan="3"></td>
              <td class="left"><a onclick="addImage();" class="button"><?php echo $button_add_image; ?></a></td>
            </tr>
          </tfoot>
        </table>
        </div>
```

and javascript code for image row is :-

```js
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    var image_row = <?php echo $image_row; ?>;

    function addImage() {
        html  = '<tbody id="image-row' + image_row + '">';
     html += '  <tr>';
     html += '    <td class="left"><div class="image"><img src="<?php echo $no_image; ?>" alt="" id="thumb' + image_row + '" /><input type="hidden" name="product_image[' + image_row + '][image]" value="" id="image' + image_row + '" /><br /><a onclick="image_upload(\'image' + image_row + '\', \'thumb' + image_row + '\');" id="simple-image"><?php echo $text_browse; ?></a>  |  <a onclick="$(\'#thumb' + image_row + '\').attr(\'src\', \'<?php echo $no_image; ?>\'); $(\'#image' + image_row + '\').attr(\'value\', \'\');"><?php echo $text_clear; ?></a></div></td>';
     html += '    <td class="right"><input type="text" name="product_image[' + image_row + '][sort_order]" value="" size="2" /></td>';
     html += '    <td class="left"><a onclick="$(\'#image-row' + image_row  + '\').remove();" class="button"><?php echo $button_remove; ?></a></td>';
     html += '  </tr>';
     html += '</tbody>';
     
     $('#images tfoot').before(html);
     
     image_row++;
    }
    //--></script>
```

and other javascript code that make filemanager work is :

```js
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
function image_upload(field, thumb) {
 $('#dialog').remove();
 
 $('#content').prepend('<div id="dialog" style="padding: 3px 0px 0px 0px;"><iframe src="index.php?route=common/filemanager&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&field=' + encodeURIComponent(field) + '" style="padding:0; margin: 0; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto"></iframe></div>');
 
 $('#dialog').dialog({
  title: '<?php echo $text_image_manager; ?>',
  close: function (event, ui) {
   if ($('#' + field).attr('value')) {
    $.ajax({
     url: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager/image&token=<?php echo $token; ?>&image=' + encodeURIComponent($('#' + field).attr('value')),
     dataType: 'text',
     success: function(text) {
      $('#' + thumb).replaceWith('<img src="' + text + '" alt="" id="' + thumb + '" />');
     }
    });
   }
  }, 
  bgiframe: false,
  width: 800,
  height: 400,
  resizable: false,
  modal: false
 });
};
//--></script>
```

your help please

i reached to this javascript code which make me browse image from pc put it work for first row only.
i want it work to every row that i add

```js
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

function image_upload(field, thumb) {    
var btnUpload=$('#simple-image');  
  new AjaxUpload(btnUpload, {
  action: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager/upload&image=' + encodeURIComponent($('#' + field).attr('value')),
  name: 'image',
  autoSubmit: true,
  responseType: 'json',
      
  onChange: function(file, extension) {
   
   this.setData({'directory': ''});
         this.submit();
  },
      
  onSubmit: function(file, extension) {
   $('#upload').append('<img src="catalog/view/theme/mall/image/loading.gif" class="loading" style="padding-left: 5px;" />');
  },
  onComplete: function(file, json) {
   if (json.success) {
             $('#' + field).attr('value','data/user/'+file);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'index.php?route=common/filemanager/image&image=' + encodeURIComponent($('#' + field).attr('value')),
     dataType: 'text',
     success: function(text) {
     $('#' + thumb).replaceWith('<img src="' + text + '" alt="" id="' + thumb + '" />');                          
     }
    });
   }
   
   if (json.error) {
    alert(json.error);
   }
            
   $('.loading').remove(); 
  }
   });
  
   
  };



//--></script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by without file manager?

Comment: mean with out dialog of file manager i want directly browse from pc

Comment: Have you heard about `<input type="file" />`?

Comment: yes mr.shadyyx but i want to make last code continually validate with next image_row as found in second code

Answer (score 0):

You could use an FTP manager to upload your files. Something like Filezilla, which is available for Mac Windows and Linux should work well. Just FTP to your server and you can upload them directly from your PC.

Comment: Could you clarify that?

Comment: i want to make the last javascript code that i posted to be for several image-row  according to html code in top of post